# Sorting Div by image names In Descending Order?

Tags: php, javascript

***Please Read Fully   - I'm using example coding first -then my actual to be more descriptive ***

I would like to  sort a div by DESCENDING order based on their image name.

Change From this:

```
<div id="content">
<p><img src="image/1.jpg"/></p>
<p><img src="image/3.jpg"/></p>
<p><img src="image/4.jpg"/></p>
<p><img src="image/2.jpg"/></p>
</div>
```

To This

```
<div id="content">
<p><img src="image/4.jpg"/></p>
<p><img src="image/3.jpg"/></p>
<p><img src="image/2.jpg"/></p>
<p><img src="image/1.jpg"/></p>
</div>
```

**However** I'm using this code here to populate images within the "content" div. These image paths are being pull from another directory with this code below since users are uploading images on a daily basis. That content div needs to self populate.

```
<script>
$.ajax({
  url: "user-uploads-thumbnails",
  success: function(data){
     $(data).find("a:contains(.jpg)").each(function(){
        // will loop through 
var images = 'user-uploads-thumbnails/' + $(this).attr("href");
var linkimage = 'user-uploads/' + $(this).attr("href");
 //backup $('<p><a href="' + linkimage + '"><img src="' + images + '"></a></p>').appendTo('#content');
$('<p><a class="fancybox" href="' + linkimage + '" data-fancybox-group="gallery"><img src="' + images + '"></a></p>').appendTo('#content');
     });
  }
});
</script>
```

**This Script below works ONLY when I hard code the urls into the "content" div. However, Images are going to be added to the other directory daily, and I need it to self populate. When I use the script above to pull the paths  ^^ it doesn't work.**

```
<script>
function sort(container) {
    var images = [],
        paragraphs = container.getElementsByTagName('p');        
    while(!!paragraphs.length) {
        var p = paragraphs[0];
        images.push(p.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].getAttribute('src'));
        container.removeChild(p);
    }
    images = images.sort();
    console.log(images);
    for(var i = images.length; i-- > 0;) {
        var p = document.createElement('p'),
            img = document.createElement('img');
            img.src = images[i];
            p.appendChild(img);
        container.appendChild(p);
    }
}

var container = document.getElementById('content');
sort(container);
</script>
```

Comment: What is the format for `data` returned from `user-uploads-thumbnails` via `ajax`

Answer (score 1):

I think its good to make sure, 'sort(container)' gets called once all content has been loaded and appended via AJAX call.

Something like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "user-uploads-thumbnails",
  success: function(data){
  var count = $(data).find("a:contains(.jpg)").length // storing total number of images
  $(data).find("a:contains(.jpg)").each(function(){
    // will loop through 
    var images = 'user-uploads-thumbnails/' + $(this).attr("href");
    var linkimage = 'user-uploads/' + $(this).attr("href");
    //backup $('<p><a href="' + linkimage + '"><img src="' + images + '"></a></p>').appendTo('#content');
    $('<p><a class="fancybox" href="' + linkimage + '" data-fancybox-group="gallery"><img src="' + images + '"></a></p>').appendTo('#content');

    if (!--count) sort(container); // calling sort after everything is loaded
   });
 }
});
```

Comment: He will loose the `<a class="fancybox" href="' + linkimage + '" data-fancybox-group="gallery">` in final result if he uses old sort function. The sort function also need to be updated to include `<a>`

Comment: @sabithpocker what do you mean old sort function? Where does the updated <a> go?

Comment: old sort funtion is your 'below' code `function sort(container) {` . Varinder is suggesting that you call that `sort` function from your `success` call back of your 'above' code after you have appended your result.  You should use an array for `links` like the `images` array and keep track of links using that. And in the for loop create '<a>' elements and give it those `href` like how `src` is given to `img` . At last do something like `a.appendChild(img)` and `p.appendChild(a)` . So you get a `p->a->img` structure.

Comment: Also give the structure of `data` returned from server and what result you are getting now, syntax error, logic error, nothing happens. This will help understand the problem.

Comment: @sabithpocker the scripts are running now on this page here [link](http://ilovesmallies.com/forum/showcase.php)

The order of the pictures should be reversed and nothing is currently happening.

Comment: Oh discard my previous comment (dint noticed valid answer below). MrSeith, would you mind marking that answer as approved? -Thanks and Happy Halloween! :)

Answer (score 1):

I took a look at your site.

**Point No1.**

Wrap javascript in document `ready` event. (Google and find why)

**Point No2.**

If you dont want masonry, comment it like

```
/*$(function() {
  $(window).load(function(){
    $('#content').masonry();
  });*/
```

not like

```
//$(function() {
  $(window).load(function(){
    $('#content').masonry();
  });
```

**Sorting code can be**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.fancybox').fancybox();
    $.ajax({
        url: "user-uploads-thumbnails",
        success: function(data){
            var imageNames = [];
            $(data).find("a:contains(.jpg)").each(function(){
                // store each image name into array
                imageNames.push($(this).attr("href"));
               });
            //imagenames array is ~ 
            //['1351732586.jpg' ,'1351732519.jpg' ,'1351732583.jpg' ,'1351732473.jpg' ....]
            var sortedImageNames = imageNames.sort();
            //sortedImageNames array is ~ 
            //["1351732473.jpg", "1351732519.jpg", "1351732583.jpg", "1351732586.jpg" ....]
            //In for loop we take from last image to first Image for DESC order
            for(var i = sortedImageNames.length; i-- > 0;) {
                    var linkImage = 'user-uploads/' + sortedImageNames[i];
                    var thumbnailImage = 'user-uploads-thumbnails/' + sortedImageNames[i];
                    var item = '<p><a class="fancybox" href="' 
                        + linkImage 
                        + '" data-fancybox-group="gallery"><img src="' 
                        + thumbnailImage 
                        + '"></a></p>';
                    $(item).appendTo('#content');
                }
            //Apply fancybox to these Elements
            $('.fancybox').fancybox();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is not tested.

Comment: Sabith, this worked perfectly.. thanks for your input...

Now I need to get an infinite scroll feature implemented on this page..

Answer (score 0):

You need to sort the container every time after the #content div is loaded via ajax. Just add
`sort(container);` after you've done appending all the content in the ajax success callback.

```
<script>
$.ajax({
  url: "user-uploads-thumbnails",
  success: function(data){
     $(data).find("a:contains(.jpg)").each(function(){
    // will loop through 
var images = 'user-uploads-thumbnails/' + $(this).attr("href");
var linkimage = 'user-uploads/' + $(this).attr("href");
 //backup $('<p><a href="' + linkimage + '"><img src="' + images + '"></a></p>').appendTo('#content');
$('<p><a class="fancybox" href="' + linkimage + '" data-fancybox-group="gallery"><img src="' + images + '"></a></p>').appendTo('#content');
 });

sort(container); // sort after loading the content

 }
});
</script>
```